# How to resolve service name to in docker swarm mode for hyperledger composer?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, hyperledger-composer

I am using docker swarm mode for hyperledger composer setup and I am new to docker. My fabric is running okay. When I use service names in connection.json file, it results into "REQUEST_TIMEOUT" while installing network. But when I use IP address of host instead of service name all works fine. So,how can I resolve service name/container name?

Here is my peer configuration:

```
peer1:
deploy:
  replicas: 1
  restart_policy:
    condition: on-failure
    delay: 5s
    max_attempts: 3
hostname: peer1.eprocure.org.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$ARCH-1.1.0
networks:
  hyperledger-ov:
    aliases:
      - peer1.eprocure.org.com
environment:
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.eprocure.org.com
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.eprocure.org.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=eProcureMSP
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1:5984
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=hyperledger-ov

  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.eprocure.org.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_ENDORSER_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true
  - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true

working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
command: peer node start
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - /export/composer/genesis-folder:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    - /export/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/eprocure.org.com/peers/peer1.eprocure.org.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
    - /export/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/eprocure.org.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
ports:
  - 8051:7051
  - 8053:7053
```

And here is my current connection.json with IP

```
"peers": {
    "peer0.eprocure.org.com": {
        "url": "grpc://192.168.0.147:7051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://192.168.0.147:7053"
    },
    "peer1.eprocure.org.com": {
        "url": "grpc://192.168.0.147:8051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://192.168.0.147:8053"
    },
    "peer2.eprocure.org.com": {
        "url": "grpc://192.168.0.147:9051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://192.168.0.147:9053"
    }
},
```

I have tried following before.

```
"peers": {
    "peer0.eprocure.org.com": {
        "url": "grpc://peers_peer0:7051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://peers_peer0:7053"
    },
    "peer1.eprocure.org.com": {
        "url": "grpc://peers_peer1:8051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://peers_peer2:8053"
    },
    "peer2.eprocure.org.com": {
        "url": "grpc://peers_peer2:9051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://peers_peer2:9053"
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. 
Can anyone please let me know how can I solve my problem?

Comment: as mentioned on Rocketchat, its because the containers can resolve those container names (on the same docker network). In your case, with docker swarm, your containers are in different services - you probably need container discovery - see more in the answer section here -> https://superuser.com/questions/1218363/how-do-i-properly-resolve-the-ip-of-another-container-in-a-docker-swarm-dns - or hopefully someone from docker-swarm tagged community can help you with this networking issue.